# Reactjs How to pass parameter in onclick event in jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx

How to pass parameter using the jsx in reactjs?

this is my code

```
  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

.....

<Button 
  color="primary" 
  size="small"
  onClick={handleClick}
  className={classes.notificationbutton}>
     View
</Button>
```

Comment: you want to pass parameters to `handleClick`?

Comment: yes please......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As default, `onClick` is passing an [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) parameter.

You can create arrow key function and call your `handleClick` there with custom parameters:

```
<Button 
  color="primary" 
  size="small"
  onClick={(event) => handleClick(param1, param2)}
  className={classes.notificationbutton}
>
  View
</Button>
```